# CKEditor jumps to other page

Tags: wysiwyg

Strange behavior: when editing a page, the html code is shortly displayed, after a few seconds the wysiwyg is displayed of another page, including the admin menu and other blocks. It happens only with new created pages, not with older ones.

The "other" page displayed is the civicrm (new) contribution page, with address:

```
?q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1
```

To route the **user/register** link to this civicrm page,
we needed to link to an intermediate page with only one php function:

```
drupal_goto('civicrm/contribute/transact',
 array('query'=>array('reset'=>'1', 'id'=>'1')
 )
```

A direct link does not work.

Now, it seems, when editing new pages, this intermediate page function is activated,
and the all civicrm page (including all menues and blocks) is displayed!

So why is this page activated and how to prevent (or bypass) it?

Comment: Very strange; can you replicate this issue on a clean install? Did you try using WYSIWYG with some other editor instead, just to see how will it behave?

Comment: I assume the behaviour stops if you disable ckeditor? Have you tried a different editor?